Ceiling Fix: Chimney or something else?
I bought an old 1929 house a few years ago. It's a cape cod style, 1.5 floors. There's two chimneys. The one in the picture is small and goes to the basement--probably the old coal furnace. It's currently used for the gas water heater exhaust. Over the last six years, some yellowing has slowly (I mean really slowly) appeared where the ceiling and the chimney (which was plastered over) meet; and the ceiling around the chimney is cracking (again, very slowly). I take pictures to track it.
I need some help diagnosing what's going on so I don't just fix the ceiling with the problem returning or getting worse. I'm thinking of three possibilities for the ceiling damage, but would appreciate more ideas:

an issue with the chimney itself. I had a chimney company come, and the guy said that the bricks are likely "sweating" moisture that enters the chimney. They offered to properly cap it (the previous owners put an off-center piece of sheet metal on it) and do some tuck pointing. Flashing looks good.

There's a bathroom vent some six feet from the chimney that goes into the attic. I know that's bad, but the exhaust is next to an open, screened gable so that seems to have mitigated a lot of possible problems (no mold, etc.). But maybe the moisture--maybe even humidity from outside--is dripping down the brick? I can't see any water marks.

Perhaps heat contraction from the chimney against the ceiling?

Other ideas?


I'm pretty handy, but I can't do roof stuff, or heights in general, so I'm going to have to hire someone if the solution involves going on the roof. I'm just not sure where to invest right now (money is tight). A chimney company quoted $1,300 for a cap and tuck pointing, but I'm a tad uncomfortable at the cost considering that no one actually went on the roof (just visual inspection from the ground), and if this fix doesn't solve the ceiling issue, then I'm back to square one. Venting the bathroom fan might be cheaper. I'm trying to establish priorities that stops the damage to the ceiling since that is the only obvious problem.
I'd be thankful for some suggestions or ideas.

Too many maybes.  You need to find where the moisture/water is coming from exactly instead of guessing.  Often water will leave stains showing where it comes from.  Roof leak is another possible source.  Water usually travels from where it enters to where it finally stains a ceiling.  A ceiling stain is often not exactly beneath a water/roof leak.

I'm not seeing a picture...

Some things are apparently necessary even if it doesn't singularly explain the present problem. Chimneys need caps. Why not vent the gas water heater through a wall penetration while you're at it? It's relatively inexpensive to do this. Venting exhaust up the chimney is likely to deposit condensate as it cools over its long trek.
